# Pooling LSTM output if input met certain conditions

Tags: python, keras, lstm, max-pooling

I'm trying to recreate this architecture.
[image]

The model has embeddings and LSTM layer **followed by pooling layer**.

I'm stuck on how to pool multiple LSTM outputs. (not pooling time sequence).

for example, if the LSTM input sequences are: 

Start1 - A - B - C - End1 

Start1 - C - D - E - End1

I want this 2 sequence LSTM-outputs to be pooled first (as prediction output (max or avg)) before the LSTM take the learning step. 
(Pooled because they have the same start and end).

I expect something like this:

```
input_layer = Input()
x = Embedding()(input_layer)
x = LSTM()(x)
output = ConditionalPooling()(x)
```

The question is how to implement the `ConditionalPooling`, where `ConditionalPooling` is a function to group sequences output which has the same head and tails.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you provide information about the paper, for further explanation if what you want to do. Also, if you are looking for something like `if` statement care about the differentiabliness if your layer.

Comment: @OSainz this is the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04540.pdf), and this is the original [repository](https://github.com/eBay/KPRN)